# Nodejs difference between two paths

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get the difference between two path. I've come with a solution, but I am not really happy about it, even if it works. Is there a better / easier way to do this?

```
var firstPath =  '/my/first/path'
  , secondPath = '/my/first/path/but/longer'

// what I want to get is: '/but/longer'

// my code:
var firstPathDeconstruct = firstPath.split(path.sep)
  , secondPathDeconstruct = secondPath.split(path.sep)
  , diff = []

secondPathDeconstruct.forEach(function(chunk) {
  if (firstPathDeconstruct.indexOf(chunk) < 0) {
    diff.push(chunk)
  }
})

console.log(diff)
// output ['but', 'longer']
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Node provides a standard function, `path.relative`, which does exactly this and also handles all of the various relative path edge cases that you might encounter:

From the [online docs](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to):

> ## `path.relative(from, to)`
>
> Solve the relative path from `from` to `to`.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> path.relative('C:\\orandea\\test\\aaa', 'C:\\orandea\\impl\\bbb')
> // returns
> '..\\..\\impl\\bbb'
>
> path.relative('/data/orandea/test/aaa', '/data/orandea/impl/bbb')
> // returns
> '../../impl/bbb'
> ```

Comment: I took a look at it before and for some reason thought it was not appropriate. But it is. Thanks